# URL Routing with ASP.NET 4.0 The resource cannot be found error

Tags: c#, url-routing, asp.net-webpages

I am trying  to implement simple page routing, for some reason it is not working. I have cross checked almost everything but still nothing seems to works.

I list all the activities on `Activities.aspx` & Show details of Activities of activity on `Activity-Details.aspx` page.

link on `Activities.aspx` page after URL Routing implementation are like
`http://localhost:49442/website/en/activity/en-US/44/31/event-title-will-go-here`

When i click on the link it always show me error message

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /website/en/activity/en-US/44/31/event-title-will-go-here
```

I am working on a multilingual website where i keep separate language specific files under particular folder English under **en** & Arabic under **ar** and folder structure like

```
/ 
/en
/en/Activities.aspx
/en/Activity-Details.aspx
...
/ar
/ar/Activities.aspx
/ar/Activity-Details.aspx
...
/images
/css
```

I have URL routing working for other projects but in this one i am missing something.

Code for Global.asax file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.exe/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapPageRoute("ActivityRoute", "activity/{Language}/{EventID}/{PageID}/{EventTitle}", "~/en/Activity-Details.aspx", false,
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Language", "en-US"},
                    { "EventID", "0" },
                    { "PageID", "0"},
                    { "EventTitle", "event-not-found" }},
                new RouteValueDictionary {   
                    {"Language", "[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}"},
                    { "EventID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "PageID", "[0-9]{1,8}" }
                });
}
```

**WEB.Config**
Do i need to make any change to the web.config file for url routing to work. I have following entry in the web.config. I removed it but it is still not working..

```
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

I have included `using System.Web.Routing` on `Activity-Details.aspx` page also. but i am not sure why i keep getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and enable [Route Debugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger). It will tell you which and why each route is(n't) being hit.

By the way, you don't have this part of your url mapped in your route: website/en/

Comment: I think you got it i am not using complete route it should be like  routes.MapPageRoute("ActivityRoute", "en/activity/{Language}/{EventID}/{PageID}/{EventTitle}",.....